# Scraping through multiple pages when url doesn't change

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to scrape through all the pages in the (link)[https://mahabocw.in/safety-kit-benefits-distribution/]. But the url doesn't change when I move to the next page. I tried to use selenium, but I am stuck as I don't know how to click the next page. Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated.

I have implemented the following code till now.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://mahabocw.in/safety-kit-benefits-distribution/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
```

Below is the button element I need to click

```
<button type="button" class="ag-paging-button">Next</button>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.
[1]: https://mahabocw.in/safety-kit-benefits-distribution/

Comment: It's because they use http request to refresh the page information. You have to look for mouse clicks events in selenium documentation or learn abouts requests library and reproduce the browser requests.

Comment: How could I use requests library here. Could you share some code. I am a noob in this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell selenium to click the next button.  Add this to your code and see if it works.

```
next_button = '/html/body/div/div[6]/div/article/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[2]/div[3]/button'
click_next = driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_button)
click_next.submit()
```

You might have to use click_next.click() instead of .submit() depending on the page. Also, to get the 'next_button' you just inspect elements on the page, find the item you want, and click copy as xpath.

Comment: The code doesn't work. I receive the following error : `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"./ancestor-or-self::form"}`

Comment: Actually `click_next` seems to retrieve the element correctly, but the last line causes the above mentioned error. I changed it to `click_next.click()` and it works now. Thanks man.

Comment: Thank you. And for anyone reading it afterwards, you can use a `xpath finder` extension in your browser to find the path as in the variable `next_button`

Comment: Sorry I am just now seeing this. I believe it depends on the item on the page for how you click it. When I was using this work on a project I had to use .submit() but i know on other pages .click() works also. Glad you got it working!

Comment: Actually `.click()` was the one that worked for me. You could edit your answer. Thanks again.